# dyld: Symbol not found: _kABPersonAddressCityKey XCODE 8 issue

Tags: ios, xcode8

Hi My code was running perfectly in xcode `7.x.x`

As soon as i updated my xcode i am getting this issue please give me the solution for this.

Details :

> dyld: Symbol not found: _kABPersonAddressCityKey   Referenced from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0A16B18D-CB72-4FCA-94F7-422AFD1411AD/ABCD.app/ABCD
>   Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/PassKit.framework/PassKit  in
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/0A16B18D-CB72-4FCA-94F7-422AFD1411AD/ABCD.app/ABCD

Answer (score 29):

Add `PassKit.framework` to your **Link Binary With Libraries** in your **Build Phases** and set its **Status** to `Optional`

[image]

Comment: Is anyone able to explain why this is necessary?  As I understand PassKit is a system framework that should exist on all iOS devices already and therefore its not essential to link it.

Comment: This didn't worked. The same error occurs for me in `xCode 8.3.3`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that might fix your problem:

1- Open your target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Add AddressBook.framework

2- 
AddressBook framework was deprecated in iOS 9. Apparently your app will crash if you compile the code on Xcode 8 and run on a iOS 9 or lower device.

> I recommend migrating to Contacts framework and/or have preprocessor macros that don't include the AddressBook framework code when built on iOS 10.

Source: https://github.com/OceanLabs/iOS-Print-SDK/issues/257

Answer (score 0):

Paul Senabre's solution worked for me, thank you, thank you, thank you! This has been driving me nuts!

Adding PassKit.framework solved but problem, **but make sure to add it for all of your targets**! When you add it, it only affects your current target. BTW, my app with a target of iOS-8 ran fine with iOS-10 in Xcode-8, but would crash with anything previous to iOS-10.