# Got Xcode 8 and my app only runs on IOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, xcode8

A few days ago I got the update for Xcode 8. I did some testing for my app to make sure every thing works. I submitted my app to the App Store with Xcode 8 and got it on my iPad that is on IOS 9, but it crashed. What is weird is that it still works on IOS 10. I did not change any of the program that would effect IOS 9. Is there some thing I am missing or am I the only one with this issue? This is all it gives me when it crashes.[image]
If there any information that I should provide please tell me because I need to get this fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: It doesn't show a stack trace for you?

Comment: I put on the exception breakpoint but it also crashes saying ->  0x10d3a7001 <+1>: nop    Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subside=0x0)

Comment: What does Deployment Target in Deployment Info say?

Comment: @kometen The Deployment Target is IOS 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while I found this error and fixed it from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485826/dyld-symbol-not-found-kabpersonaddresscitykey-xcode-8-issue). I also had to get rid of some of the old Facebook api which I had in there but wasn't using at all.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur with broken Storyboards / XIB-Files. Try exchanging your RootViewController / Storyboard with a dummy ViewController / Storyboard just to validate this theory. If it works then, you should re-setup all your IBOutlets and the app delegate connection in your RootViewController's XIB respectively re-setup your storyboard.